# Python Requests: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:547)

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to login and scrape an airline website with the python Request package.  I am getting the belowe error just by trying to load the main website.  This code use to work last year but I have not tried it until now with the new Requests 2.2.1.  Any ideas what is going on?

[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:547)

I'm using Requests 2.2.1.

ssladapter.py

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

from ssl import PROTOCOL_TLSv1


class SSLAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    '''An HTTPS Transport Adapter that uses an arbitrary SSL version.'''

    __attrs__ = ['max_retries', 'config', '_pool_connections', '_pool_maxsize', '_pool_block', 'ssl_version']

def __init__(self, ssl_version=None, **kwargs):
    self.ssl_version = ssl_version

    super(SSLAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)


def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
    self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
        maxsize=maxsize, block = block,
        ssl_version=self.ssl_version)
```

scrape.py

```
import requests
import ssladapter
from ssl import PROTOCOL_TLSv1

session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', ssladapter.SSLAdapter(ssl_version=PROTOCOL_TLSv1))

request = session.get("www.delta.com")
```

!!! SSLERROR raised here.

Answer (score 1):

This Error is not a problem of the Requests library because it has been rigorously tested.

This is an indication of a ['Man-in-the-middle' attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

May be you may be having a Network Sniffing tool like Fiddler or Wireshark running.

More Detailed Info on this a [related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502814/2758759)
Here it is suggested that this is how SSL should work.